# jQuery Image Draggable with Marker Draggable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use `jQuery Draggable` on image background and it's work.

I can drag the image everywhere.

Now I have `div` marker to identify every location on the image. In example code I put `Michael Office` that should be on Michael area (see on the image). But I can't figure it out how to make the marker place into Michael Area.

My question is it possible to put the marker into Michael Area and also when I drag anywhere, the Michael Area marker should be keep there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const container = document.querySelector('.img');
    const containerSize = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    let imagePosition = { x: 50, y: 50 };
    let cursorPosBefore = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let imagePosBefore = null;
    let imagePosAfter = imagePosition;

    // Helpers
    const minMax = (pos) => (pos < 0) ? 0 : (pos > 100) ? 100 : pos;
    const setNewCenter = (x, y) => {
      imagePosAfter = { x: x, y: y }; 
      container.style.backgroundPosition = `${x}% ${y}%`;
    };

    const getImageZoom = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let actualImage = new Image();
        actualImage.src = $('#img').css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
        actualImage.onload = function() {
          resolve({
            x: zoomX = this.width / containerSize.width - 1,
            y: zoomY = this.height / containerSize.height - 1
          });
        }
      });
    }
        
    const addEventListeners = (zoomLevels) => {container.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
          cursorPosBefore = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
          imagePosBefore = imagePosAfter; // Get current image position
        });

        container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            if (event.buttons === 0) return;

            let newXPos = imagePosBefore.x + ((cursorPosBefore.x - event.clientX) / containerSize.width * 100 / zoomLevels.x);
            let newYPos = imagePosBefore.y + ((cursorPosBefore.y - event.clientY) / containerSize.height * 100 / zoomLevels.y);

            setNewCenter(minMax(newXPos), minMax(newYPos));
        });
    };

    getImageZoom().then(zoom => addEventListeners(zoom));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Manrope';
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        
        #page {
            margin: 10px;
            display: flex;
        }
        
        #page .summary {
            width: 450px;
        }
        
        #page .summary .map-location {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        
        #page .summary table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        #page .summary table th {
            background: #f1f1f1;
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        
        #page .summary table td {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        #img {
            position: relative;
            width: calc(100% - 50px);
            height: calc(100vh - 25px);
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-image: url('https://live.staticflickr.com/3312/3642071233_162baf0108_h.jpg');
            cursor: move;
            border: 3px solid #5e5e5e;
        }

        #img:active {
            border-color: #007fff;
        }
        
        .table {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
        }
        
        .table-details {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        
        .scroll-helper {
            height: calc(100vh - 75px);
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        
        .tbl-data th {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }
        
        .tbl-data tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        }
        
        .pin {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
        }
        </style>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div class="img" id="img">
                <div class="pin" id="pin">Michael Office</div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: TRy to adjust the position of the marker based on the drag movement of the background image, this can be achieved by calculating the displacement of the background image and applying the same displacement to the marker's position. hope that helps

Comment: any sample code for that?

Comment: answered with sample code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code you requested

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initialPinOffset = { x: 10, y: 10 }; //Initial position of the pin, adjust as you need

    $('#img').draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var imgOffset = $(this).offset();
            initialPinOffset.x = $('#pin').offset().left - imgOffset.left;
            initialPinOffset.y = $('#pin').offset().top - imgOffset.top;
        },
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var newImgOffset = ui.position;
            $('#pin').css('left', initialPinOffset.x + newImgOffset.left);
            $('#pin').css('top', initialPinOffset.y + newImgOffset.top);
        }
    });
});
```